# PHP error message when I try to check a value from database

Tags: php, html, oop

I'm new to OOP PHP, so, past week i was searching for a simple tutorial to enter in this new world and I found a good one from Codecourse([Codecourse OOP PHP Login/Register System](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc)), but in the 14th video, I got an error that I couldn't solve or find the problem, anyone quem help me?

This is the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function count() on bool in D:\Rafael\xampp\htdocs\sywork\classes\Validate.php:37 Stack trace: #0 D:\Rafael\xampp\htdocs\sywork\register.php(9): Validate->check(Array, Array) #1 {main} thrown in D:\Rafael\xampp\htdocs\sywork\classes\Validate.php on line 37

This is the link for the my code: [My Code](https://github.com/rafaelbreno/study_2)

This is the link for the complete code(isn't mine): [Complete Code](https://github.com/emanuellimeira/PHP-Object-Oriented-Programming-Build-a-Login-System)

Here is the archives that I keep getting errors:

```
<?php
class Validate{
private $_passed = false,
        $_errors = array(),
        $_db = null;

public function __construct(){
  $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
}

public function check($source, $items = array()){
  foreach($items as $item => $rules){
    foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value){
      $value = trim($source[$item]);
      $item = escape($item);
      if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)){
        $this->addError("{$item} is required");
      } else if(!empty($value)){
        switch($rule){
          case 'min':
            if(strlen($value) < $rule_value){
              $this->addError("{$item} must be at minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
            }
          break;
          case 'max':
          if(strlen($value) > $rule_value){
            $this->addError("{$item} must be at minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
          }
          break;
          case 'matches':
            if($value != $source[$rule_value]){
              $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}.");
            }
          break;
          case 'unique':
            $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
            if($check->count()){
              $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
            }
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(empty($this->_errors)){
    $this->_passed = true;
  }

  return $this;
}

private function addError($error){
  $this->_errors[] = $error;
}

public function errors(){
  return $this->_errors;
}

public function passed(){
  return $this->_passed;
}
}
?>
```

The other one:

```
    <?php
  include_once 'core/init.php';
  if(Input::exists()){
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))){
      $validate = new Validate();
      $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array(
          //Mínimo e máximo de acordo com o banco de dados
          'required' => true,
          'min' => 2,
          'max' => 32,
          'unique' => 'users' //único na tabela users
        ),
        'password' => array(
          'required' => true,
          'min' => 2,
          'max' => 32
        ),
        'password_again' => array(
          'required' => true,
          'matches' => 'password'
        ),
        'name' => array(
          'required' => true,
          'min' => 2,
          'max' => 64
        )
      ));
      if($validation->passed()){
        $user = new User();
        echo $salt = Hash::salt(32);
        die();
        try{
          $user->create(array(
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'salt' => '',
            'name' => '',
            'joined' => '',
            'group' => ''
          ));
        } catch(Exception $e){
          die($e->getMessage());
        }
      } else{
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error){
          echo "{$error}<br>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?= Token::generate(); ?>">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?= escape(Input::get('username')); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="password_again">Enter Your Password Again: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?= escape(Input::get('name')); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: _"Call to a member function count() on bool"_ This means that you have some code like `$foo->count()` and you're expecting `$foo` to be an instance of an object, but it's actually a boolean.

Comment: Also please note, this tutorial uses some very bad techniques and outdated features.

Comment: @alexhowansky Which ones fo you have in mind?

Comment: Wrong alex, but still: no composer (custom autoload schema -- good for understanding it, bad for everything else), hardcoded config, swallowed exceptions from PDO, and even `?>` at end of files.

Comment: @Dharman Building SQL with string concatenation instead of prepared statements, using a fast hash for passwords, using the deprecated mcrypt library, using `uniqid()` for crypto-sensitive input.

Comment: Let's also add the generally frowned-upon techniques of: monolithic page design, no namespaces, no autoloading, overuse of static methods, singleton db.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I agree with your statements about hash and poor overall design, but I briefly looked around this code and saw that DB class was using prepared statements. Did I miss something?

Comment: @AlexHowansky in the code that is linked above they use prepared statements.

Comment: @Dharman I'm looking at `DB::insert` from [here](https://github.com/emanuellimeira/PHP-Object-Oriented-Programming-Build-a-Login-System/blob/master/classes/DB.php).

Comment: And that insert statement is then fed to `prepare()`. I think that's quite OK for a tutorial that teaches basics. Doctrine from starters would be an overkill.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Same. Even if they do it in a very complex way, they still use prepared statements. Nonetheless it is a plus, considering how many tutorials don't use it at all. I agree this code could be designed it much better way, shedding half of the complexity and making it more secure, however I still thinks it is much better than many others I have seen.

Comment: @Alx Ah yes, ok, thx I did not notice that.

Comment: @Dharman _"I still thinks it is much better than many others I have seen."_ Very true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On line 36 of `Validate.php` you perform a call to DB handling class. That call returns `false` as an indication of error. Without checking for `false` value, you check count (`->count()`), and that's where error occurs.

Looking at your code I think error is somewhere in SQL or maybe on DB connection level, e.g. misspelled table or column name.

It would be a good thing to check for error, at least for debugging purposes. So, changing this snippet (lines 36-39 in `Validate.php`):

```php
$check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
if($check->count()){
    $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
}
```

To this:

```php
$check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
if (!$check) {
    $this->addError("Database error.");
} elseif ($check->count()){
    $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
}
```

Will at least show error in form as a proper text, not as runtime error message or HTTP 500 error.

This one error check won't help you much, though, every place where an error might occur should be checked. To make it easier to add these numerous checks, exceptions were invented, but I believe at this stage of your learning process it is to early to introduce you to this topic.

Still, exceptions might be useful for you, because currently the code just hides all error details, and that does not help in debugging your app.

In `DB.php` there is this snippet:

```php
try{
    $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db') , Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'));
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

You can add this line in the top block to make sure no errors go unnoticed:

```php
$this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

So, final version would look like this:

```php
try{
    $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db') , Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'));
    $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

This will help you to see what exactly is wrong with your query.

As I don't have your SQL, I was not able to see what exactly is wrong in your case. But with changes mentioned above I can see that app fails when trying to talk to DB, which means the rest works OK.